# Table View And Tab Bar

Tags: ios, xcode

Table View:

[image: Table View]

Hello! I'm trying to create a multi-tab app with a table view controller inside one tab. As well as have a custom class for the table view (so I can add and remove cells) However, after fiddling around and searching all over I can't find how to do it. I am using Objective-C instead of Swift.

I have tried a cocoa touch class, but it won't let me use it as a class.

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, you can improve your question a lot by providing all related code.

Comment: As suggested, show what you have tried as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 20 bottles of Tylenol I finally found out how to do this!
OBJECTIVE-C ONLY!
Connect your table view to your "View Controller" as data source and delegate. Go to you View Controllers header file and add

Go to your AppDelegate and add the tab bar delegate. From here, you can now work your Table View from your view controller class! Awesome!